# best way to do Jasper report styling

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am new to Jasper reporting. My project has requirements for generating complex reports. . And the reports are very rich in terms of UX. I want to know the best way to do styling, layouts and also best practices. I just started looking into Jasper today.

Also I found very few tutorials like tutorialpoint and jasperassistant. Is there any best one point tutorial for Jasper(not only free tutorials)?

Also is it best to integrate Jasper with Spring?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to generate jasper report templates is,if possible, to use an external program, i reccomend ireport.

below  are tutorials created by the jasper team:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-tutorials-help

Can't say if there are advantages in integrating jasper with spring though